# 6V-12V to on/off switch conversion

Tags: relay, timer

In order to connect/disconnet a battery pack I need to use a timer (https://www.highwildoutdoors.com/products/6v-12v-universal-digital-timer) which seems has 6v-12v output. I am not sure which relay I need to use and how to the the whole thing to change the 6v-12v voltage to an on/off circuit (without any voltage). Basically I want to use the timer to connect/disconnect a battery that's connacted to another device using it to save battery usage.

Comment: There's really not much technical details on that web page. But most likely, any standard 12V automotive relay would work.

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation for a particular relay? If so this is off-topic.

Comment: I don't think this is the right timer for the job.  The fan symbol with three speed options (Hi-Med-Lo) makes me think the output might not be clean DC.

Comment: AnalogKid is right. The 6V-12V is the input and the output is the cable that connects to a motor. But regardless, what's the best way of converting a a 6v-12v output to what I am trying to do?

Comment: That timer is meant to control the 6 to 12V motor controller in a limited 1 to 30 second burst, 1 to 8 times a day. It may just be a relay, it may be pwm, or some other method of control but without a schematic, manual, or picture of the board, it's hard to tell. If you need a simple timer relay then google for "timer relay modules" or build your own "arduino timer relay" or "esp timer relay" or just "YOUR MICROCONTROLLER timer relay".

Comment: Thanks @Passerby.
yep, could use arduino, However, I need to use outside without any access to computer so I could set the time and let it handle the rest. I am using raspberry for DSLR camera triggering and the camera would be in the field for weeks where I need to start the raspberry, change camera settings and turn the raspberry off. Using Witty Pi works great but it requires the battery to be connected and I was hoping not to carry a big battery pack to keep everything running. I was able to use Woods 59744 Switch Timer with a mini toggle to do the job but can only be programmed 2 times

Comment: A microcontroller with a relay can be powered off 3 AA batteries. Or off the existing battery. Just use deep sleep modes for the lowest current usage.